AWS Cognito User httpOnly Cookie Authentication .NET Core
It is so extreme hard to understand AWS Cognito Cookie Authentication. I can not find any tutorial on how to implement User managment in an SaaS with a frontend correctly. I followed this tutorial here so far https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/integrate-amazon-cognito-authentication-with-hosted-ui-in-aspdotnet-core but i get stuck for log out the user. How can I make custom calls to the aws cognito service without the ui?
